# How to detect lound sound in audio files using Sox?

Tags: linux, audio, volume, sox

I've got several small audio files and I need to find out which ones contain loud sounds. With the `stat` command of Sox I get max and min amplitudes which are always around -1 and +1.

For example, this sound is louder:

```
$ sox out6.wav -n stat
Samples read:            220500
Length (seconds):      5.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.999939
Minimum amplitude:    -1.000000
Midline amplitude:    -0.000031
Mean    norm:          0.079951
Mean    amplitude:    -0.002050
RMS     amplitude:     0.244085
Maximum delta:         0.386505
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.007803
RMS     delta:         0.024331
Rough   frequency:          699
Volume adjustment:        1.000
```

than this one:

```
$ sox out5.wav -n stat
Samples read:            220500
Length (seconds):      5.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.999939
Minimum amplitude:    -1.000000
Midline amplitude:    -0.000031
Mean    norm:          0.035560
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000054
RMS     amplitude:     0.121909
Maximum delta:         0.085022
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.002599
RMS     delta:         0.006305
Rough   frequency:          363
Volume adjustment:        1.000
```

But they both have the same min and max amplitude.

How can I determine which one is the loudest?

Comment: I would definitely go for RMS amplitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peak amplitude is not a good measure of overall loudness. All this measurement does is find the maximum or minimum sample that occurs over a period. The problem with this is that a clip with all zeros and a single one will measure the same max peak amplitude as the clip with all ones.  The RMS (root mean square) amplitude is a better gauge of loudness. Its computed by summing the square of all of the samples and then taking the sqrt of the result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude